# Writing the Jenkins console output to a file placed in a remote server

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm working on R&D project where my idea is to trigger a `shell script` from `Jenkins` and write the console output I get to a file (text file) placed in a remote windows server. I tried looking for options but none of them were helpful.

Is there any way to write the `Jenkins` console output to a text file located in the remote server using:

1. Any post build action or
2. any external Jenkins plugins or
3. Any other different method

Is there any connectivity access required to write the output as required? Kindly help me figure out a way.

Comment: Are you writing a Jenkins plugin for your task?

Comment: I just use the`execute shell command` option in the Jenkins to trigger my shell script and give the path there to the shell script location. I want the output i get on the jenkins console to be written into a file placed in a remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for this. We can use the Jenkins REST API and it will help us read the console output and we can write it to a file and do the necessary actions.

Comment: how can we do this for jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several ways to achieve this:

- When running your shell command, redirect it to file:

  ```
  echo scripting output > myScriptOutput.txt
  ```

  Then copy the file to a remote file share:

  ```
  copy myScriptOutput.txt \\server\share\subfolder
  ```

  (can be done in either freestyle or pipeline job).
- Redirect output like above, then archive the artifacts, and use one of the [Publish Over...Plugins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over) to copy it to a remote server (can be done in a freestyle job only).
- Configure your remote server as a Jenkins node. Then, use a pipeline script like:

  ```
  node("myBuildNodeNameOrLabel") {
      bat """echo scripting output > myScriptOutput.txt"""
      stash includes: 'myScriptOutput.txt', name: 'myScriptOutput'
  } 
  node("myRemoteServerNodeNameOrLabel") {
      unstash 'myScriptOutput'
      // copy the file to another local folder outside the workspace
      bat """copy myScriptOutput.txt d:\\some\\other\\path"""
  }
  ```
- Same as above, but capture the script output using Groovy then manipulate it...

  ```
  myOutput = bat returnStdout: true, script: """echo scripting output"""
  // now do whatever you want with the Groovy var myOutput...
  ```
- The [Email-Ext](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) Plugin can send Jenkins' Console Output via e-mail.

Comment: Ah. finally a suggestion. I think the copy (scp) and archiving to artifacts looks better. I'll try this and will get back to you at the earliest. thanks. I also need to check if there is connectivity between this to the windows server as well.